# Any way to combine two MySQL IN() functions based on my need

Tags: mysql, sql

In my scenario I am given with a list of Item Number along with their respective revision numbers. I already have a query that fetches the data for a single revision of a Product ID listed in the IN() functions of the below query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT INSERTDATE, PLMID, 
MAX(CASE WHEN TAGNAME='ItemNumber' THEN TAGVALUE END) AS ItemNumber,
MAX(CASE WHEN TAGNAME='ItemRev' THEN TAGVALUE END) AS ItemRev
FROM GOLD_STG.PLM_ITEMTAG GROUP BY INSERTDATE, PLMID) WHERE ItemNumber IN ('46.ZB99')AND ItemRev IN ('1');
```

Is there any way to modify the above query so that it works for a list of item numbers and their respective item revisions? Note that I am given a list of Item Number along with their respective revision numbers. It should match the Item Number with it's revision and return the matching result - for that entire list.

EDIT:

Suppose I am provided with the following list:

```
ItemNumber       ItemRev
46.ZB99          1
46.ZB74          5
46.ZC53          3
```

I want to be able to provide the Item Numbers as well as the Item Rev from the above list in the query such that it understands correctly that revision 1 of 46.ZB99 is expected and revision 5 of 46.ZB74 is expected and so on.

Currently if I paste the ItemNumbers in its IN() function in the above query and ItemRev in its IN() function like below:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT INSERTDATE, PLMID, 
MAX(CASE WHEN TAGNAME='ItemNumber' THEN TAGVALUE END) AS ItemNumber,
MAX(CASE WHEN TAGNAME='ItemRev' THEN TAGVALUE END) AS ItemRev
FROM GOLD_STG.PLM_ITEMTAG GROUP BY INSERTDATE, PLMID) WHERE ItemNumber IN ('46.ZB99', '46.ZB74', '46.ZC53') AND ItemRev IN ('1', '5', '3');
```

Running the above query returns revsision 1, 5 and 3 for each of the 3 item numbers, which is not what I want.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Based on the title, I removed the Oracle'ish tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use tuples and `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT INSERTDATE, PLMID, 
             MAX(CASE WHEN TAGNAME = 'ItemNumber' THEN TAGVALUE END) AS ItemNumber,
             MAX(CASE WHEN TAGNAME = 'ItemRev' THEN TAGVALUE END) AS ItemRev
      FROM GOLD_STG.PLM_ITEMTAG
      GROUP BY INSERTDATE, PLMID
     ) ip
WHERE (ItemNumber, ItemRev) IN ( ('46.ZB99', '1'), ('46.ZB99', '2') );
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!